# DEPLHI - Trying to get EXIF data on library images in Android

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I am new at developing for Android, but not so new on Delphi development though. Anyway I am struggling to get EXIT data from an image (loaded from library) and show that image on the form.

Here is my code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  System.Messaging,
  {$IF CompilerVersion > 32}
  System.Permissions,
  {$ENDIF}
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics,
  FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdActns, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Objects, FMX.Layouts,
  FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo, FMX.Surfaces, FMX.ExtCtrls, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Helpers.Android, System.Actions, FMX.ActnList, FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Layout1: TLayout;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    img1: TImageControl;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FFileName: JString;
    procedure GetEXIF(const AFileName: JInputStream);
    procedure ResultNotificationMessageHandler(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage);
    procedure TakePhoto;
    {$IF CompilerVersion > 32}
    procedure TakePhotoPermissionsResultHandler(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);
   {$ENDIF}
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses
  System.IOUtils, Androidapi.Helpers, Androidapi.JNI.Media, Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.Provider, Androidapi.JNI.App, Androidapi.JNI.Os,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.JNI.Net,
  FMX.Platform.Android, DW.Androidapi.JNI.Os;

const
  cPermissionReadExternalStorage = 'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE';
  cPermissionWriteExternalStorage = 'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE';
  cPermissionCamera = 'android.permission.CAMERA';

{$IF CompilerVersion > 32}
type
  TGrantResults = TArray<TPermissionStatus>;

  TGrantResultsHelper = record helper for TGrantResults
  public
    function AreAllGranted: Boolean;
  end;

{ TGrantResultsHelper }

function TGrantResultsHelper.AreAllGranted: Boolean;
var
  LStatus: TPermissionStatus;
begin
  for LStatus in Self do
  begin
    if LStatus <> TPermissionStatus.Granted then
      Exit(False); // <======
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
{$ENDIF}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
{$IF CompilerVersion > 32}
  TPermissionsService.DefaultService.RequestPermissions([cPermissionReadExternalStorage, cPermissionWriteExternalStorage, cPermissionCamera], TakePhotoPermissionsResultHandler);
{$ELSE}
  TakePhoto;
{$ENDIF}
end;

constructor TForm1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage(TMessageResultNotification, ResultNotificationMessageHandler);
end;

destructor TForm1.Destroy;
begin
  TMessageManager.DefaultManager.Unsubscribe(TMessageResultNotification, ResultNotificationMessageHandler);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.GetEXIF(const AFileName: JInputStream);
var
  LEXIF: JExifInterface;
  LLatLong: TJavaArray<Single>;
  LStream: JFileInputStream;
begin
  try
    LEXIF := TJExifInterface.JavaClass.init(AFileName);
    Memo1.Lines.Clear;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Date Taken: ' + JStringToString(LEXIF.getAttribute(TJExifInterface.JavaClass.TAG_DATETIME)));
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Camera Make: ' + JStringToString(LEXIF.getAttribute(TJExifInterface.JavaClass.TAG_MAKE)));
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Camera Model: ' + JStringToString(LEXIF.getAttribute(TJExifInterface.JavaClass.TAG_MODEL)));
    LLatLong := TJavaArray<Single>.Create(2);
    try
      if LEXIF.getLatLong(LLatLong) then
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Latitude: ' + LLatLong.Items[0].ToString);
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Longitude: ' + LLatLong.Items[1].ToString);
      end;
    finally
      LLatLong.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(e.Message);
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.ResultNotificationMessageHandler(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage);
var
  LMessage: TMessageResultNotification;
  Str: string;
  FullPhotoUri: Jnet_Uri;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
  jis: JInputStream;
  b: TJavaArray<Byte>;
  NativeBitmap: JBitmap;
  Bitmap: TBitmapSurface;
begin
  if M is TMessageResultNotification then
  begin
    LMessage := TMessageResultNotification(M);
    if LMessage.RequestCode = 10011 then
      if (LMessage.ResultCode = TJActivity.JavaClass.RESULT_OK) then
        if Assigned(LMessage.Value) then
        try
          try
            FullPhotoUri := LMessage.Value.getData();

            jis := TAndroidHelper.Context.getContentResolver.openInputStream(FullPhotoUri);

            GetEXIF(jis);

            ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
            b := TJavaArray<Byte>.Create(jis.available);
            jis.read(b);
            ms.Write(b.Data^, b.Length);

            img1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(ms);

            jis.close;

          except
            on E: Exception do
              Application.ShowException(e);
          end;
        finally
          ms.Free;
        end;

  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.TakePhotoPermissionsResultHandler(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);
begin
  if TGrantResults(AGrantResults).AreAllGranted then
    TakePhoto
  else
    ShowMessage('Not all photo permissions granted!');
end;


// Based on: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#java
procedure TForm1.TakePhoto;
var
  LIntent: JIntent;
  LFile, LDir: JFile;
  LUri: Jnet_Uri;
  LFileName: string;
begin
  LIntent := TJIntent.Create;
  LIntent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).addCategory(TJIntent.JavaClass.CATEGORY_OPENABLE).setType(StringToJString('image/*'));

  if LIntent.resolveActivity(TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageManager) <> nil then
  begin
    MainActivity.startActivityForResult(LIntent, 10011);
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('Cannot take a photo!');

end;

end.
```

Now, the error comes from the line:

```
img1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(ms);
```

and the error is:

> Project ObtainPhotoInfoDemo.apk raised exception class
>   Segmentation fault (11).

Thanks

**UPDATE**

**FOUND THE SOLUTION!!!!**

[blackapps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12121419/blackapps) commented and gave me an idea, the stream should be closed and reopened again to be used in an another call like this:

```
    FullPhotoUri := LMessage.Value.getData();
    //get input stream
    jis := TAndroidHelper.Context.getContentResolver.openInputStream(FullPhotoUri);
    GetEXIF(jis);
    //have to close it because GetEXIF already consumed it
    jis.close;
    //open it again
    jis := TAndroidHelper.Context.getContentResolver.openInputStream(FullPhotoUri);

    NativeBitmap := TJBitmapFactory.JavaClass.decodeStream(jis);
    Surf := TBitmapSurface.Create;
    if JBitmapToSurface(NativeBitmap, Surf) then
      img1.Bitmap.Assign(Surf);

    jis.close;
```

Comment: TJExifInterface accepts a filepath in your code. So why are you telling that you cant use it because it accepts a stream?

Comment: Bitmaps dont contain exif info so using that handler will not do.

Comment: Use the handler that delivers a file path or uri. Or start tje camera intent indicating a file uri which you determined.

Comment: thanks, I will try that way then

Comment: @blackapps how can I override onActivityResult so I can find out which image is selected?

Comment: That depends on the action that triggered it. For me its unclear which action you use. You did not tell for instance if you let the user select an image file or if you started a camera app. And further i do not program in Delphi.

Comment: Ive managed to get through more, but still, I am receiving now another error, please check call getEXIF(FullPhotoUri.getPath);  and text that Ive added under code snippet, thanks

Comment: Getdata() gives you the uri to the file. You got a nice content scheme there. Use it to let the content resolver open an input stream for it. Then you have your stream.

Comment: Why didnt you remove all that irrelevant code yet. Only code for calling the intent and onActivityResult() would do.

Comment: I did called content resolver with it and it worked perfectly, but now I am facing another issue is how to display that image on the form (I think this maybe Delphi specific)

Comment: That looks a pretty basic task. You should be able to find examples.

Comment: yes, I know it should be, but in Delphi we have to use helper functions to convert streams, strings etc. and that is producing those issues

Comment: `how to display that image on the form` On the form? On an image view i suppose? In java it would simply be `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`... And you have your bitmap already.

Comment: Before messing around with exif try `img1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(jis);`

Comment: `jis: JInputStream;` J? What kind of stream is that? Isn't there a 'normal' InputStream?

Comment: `GetEXIF(jis);` That statement will have consumed part of or the whole stream. So after that `jis.available` will not work. You should open a new stream first.

Comment: @blackapps "GetEXIF(jis); That statement will have consumed part of or the whole stream. So after that jis.available will not work. You should open a new stream first." - THAT IS IT! That solved all my problems, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Dejan and blackapps learnt much about your code many thanks.

To contribute this topic, kindly be informed that Android updated image metadata and bitmap access with Android 29+ SAF:

[Access documents and other files from shared storage Android Developers - Open a document - Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#bitmap)

[Delphi translation](https://github.com/emozgun/delphi-android-SAF)

```pascal
//Examine document metadata

  procedure dumpImageMetaData(uri : JNet_Uri);  (* GoruntuMetaVerisiDokumu *)
  // The query, because it only applies to a single document, returns only
  // one row. There's no need to filter, sort, or select fields,
  // because we want all fields for one document.
  var
    displayName, size : JString;
    sizeIndex : integer;
    cursor : JCursor;
  begin
    cursor := TAndroidHelper.Activity.getContentResolver.query(uri,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil);
    try
      // moveToFirst() returns false if the cursor has 0 rows. Very handy for
      // "if there's anything to look at, look at it" conditionals.
      if (cursor<>nil) then
        if (cursor.moveToFirst) then
        begin
          displayName := cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex (TJOpenableColumns.JavaClass.DISPLAY_NAME));
          Memo1.Lines.Add({TAG.ToString +} 'Display Name: ' + JStringToString (displayName));
          sizeIndex:=cursor.getColumnIndex(TJOpenableColumns.JavaClass.SIZE);
          size := nil;
          if not (cursor.isNull(sizeIndex)) then
            size := cursor.getString(sizeIndex)
          else
            size:=StringToJString ('Unknown');
          Memo1.Lines.Add({TAG.ToString +} 'Size: ' + JStringToString (size));
        end;
    finally
      cursor.close;
    end;
  end;



//Open a document - Bitmap

  function getBitmapFromUri(uri : JNet_Uri): JBitmap;   (* UridenBiteslemAl *)
  var
    fileDescriptor : JFileDescriptor;
    parcelFileDescriptor : JParcelFileDescriptor;
    image : JBitmap;
  begin
    Result := nil;
    try
      parcelFileDescriptor := TAndroidHelper.Activity
        .getContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri,StringToJString('r'));
      fileDescriptor := parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor;
      image := TJBitmapFactory.JavaClass.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
      parcelFileDescriptor.close;
      result := image;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        ShowMessage(e.Message);
    end;
```