# Open an image file located on a shared network drive on an Android device

Tags: android, delphi, network-drive

I have a network drive setup with a directory containing .jpg image files that I'd like to be able to load into a Timage component. I'm loading the picture name in from a database field. Below is the procedure that it supposed to accomplish this.

```
procedure TForm1.ShowPicture;
var
  fn: string;
begin
  BitMapPath := '\\DRIVE-ABC\Pictures\';
  qryPictures.Open;
  qryPictures.First;
  if not(qryPictures.FindField('Picture').IsNull) then
  begin
    fn := BitMapPath + qryPictures.FieldByName('Picture').AsString;
    TDialogService.ShowMessage(fn);
    imgPart.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(fn);
  end;
end;
```

When the TDialogService.ShowMessage(fn) executes it shows that my file path is correct

```
\\DRIVE-ABC\Pictures\123456.jpg
```

But then when .LoadFromFile(fn) line executes I get an error stating...

```
Cannot open file "/\\DRIVE-ABC\Pictures\123456.jpg". Not a directory.
```

This error only occurs when I run the program from my Android Tablet, if I compile the program as a windows x32 to run on my desktop then it retrieves the file without issue.

Now I think the issue may lie in one of two places:

1. When I normally access this drive from another computer, I have to put in my login credentials. Maybe it can't access the drive because it can't authenticate the device? How do I do this?
2. In that error is seems to add a forward slash to the beginning of my address string. I mean that would certainly make the address incorrect but I don't know why it adds that on the .LoadFromFile execution or how to stop it from doing that.

Please Help!

Comment: Those functions cannot be used for Windows shares as Samba protocol is not implemented for them.

Comment: Google for jcifs and smbj library.

Comment: How do you setup the "shared network drive" on your Android device?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done via intents. Here is a pointer in that ierection.

[DEPLHI - Trying to get EXIF data on library images in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60155948/deplhi-trying-to-get-exif-data-on-library-images-in-android)

Android likes a URI with an itnent which has a very temporay token to allow access to it.

Intent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);